# hot to update particular object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

How to update particular object based on condition in javascript

I have a object named obj, based on condition:

`'in'=="credit"` and `'out'=="bank"` and `"id"=="trans"`, get the object and add default as `'in'=="bank"` and `'out'=="bank"` and `"id"=="fund`.

`'in'=="debit"` and `'out'=="bank"` and `"id"=="fund"`, get the object and add default as `'in'=="bank"` and `'out'=="bank"` and `"id"=="trans"`.

I tried filter but got stuck

```
function getValue(send,receive, id){
 const temp = obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3)
    this.selectedProviderList = temp.filter(x=>x.in== send && x.in ==receive && x.id==id);
}

getValue("credit", "bank", "trans");
```

```
var obj = [{
    "btob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
    "ctob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
 "dtob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
}]
```

```
// get the values if 'in' is 'credit' and 'out' is 'bank' and id is "trans" 

Expected Output
[
   {
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }
]
// get the values if 'in' is 'debit' and 'out' is 'bank' and id is "fund" 

[{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. For the expected output, the first object in the array is due to the filtered `in`, `out` and `fund` values. But where does the second object in the array come from?

Answer (score 1):

Since `in` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, you'd need to use `[]` (square bracket) notation. (I also changed the second `in` to `out`).

```
function getValue(send, receive, id) {
  const temp = obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([, val]) => val)).flat(3);
  this.selectedProviderList = temp.filter(x => x["in"] == send && x["out"] == receive && x["id"] == id);
}

getValue("credit", "bank", "trans");
```